# Allow grouped product in Bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, grouped-products

So I don't think this can be done out of the box and I'm stuck on how to implement this.  I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

I want to allow the option in a dropdown or similar to select from a range of grouped products. So kind of like a bundle product, where in the bundle items, I could have one option that has a dropdown that shows grouped products.  I am planning to try adding grouped products to the allowed types for bundle products (via. updating appropriate the configuration xml).  But anyhow, I don't know if that's a good idea to allow in any case.

Basically, this is how I want to map my product:

Product with a dropdown to choose:

- Option 1 (grouped product consisting of Product A and Product B)
- Option 2 (grouped product consisting of Product C and Product D)
- Option 3 (grouped product consisting of Product E and Product E)

Any ideas or has anyone implemented products like this.

Comment: From your product grouping, I gather some products cannot be grouped together (example A,C and E, or A and D, etc) ?

Comment: It's not required to allow products A - F to mix.  Basically, Product A & B for example are simple products that go together in terms of what we want to sell.  If that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think this would work:

- Create a bundle product
- Create 2 bundle options, each of which gets a drop-down on product page

  - Option 1 - Choices: A, C or E
  - Option 2 - Choices: B, D or F
- On product page, use javascript - hide the 2nd drop-down and automatically select B, D or F depending on whether A, C or E is selected.

Comment: Not quite, as there are no dependencies.  The user would selection option 1,2 or 3 (so in each option, they choose a set combination of products).  Thanks for the suggestion however!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be of any help, but there exists extensions that allow for option dependencies on products.

A practical example would be this: http://www.transtek.com.au/crystal-xp2i-ex-digital-test-gauge.html where I used one such extension, to allow certain configurable options on the products to change as the product is built.

I don't recall the actual extension used (was a few years back, and I no longer have access to the code).

Just an idea to investigate, as it will be simpler than to create a new product type.